# Firebase Notification vs WebpushNotification

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Does com.google.firebase.messaging.Notification conform to the same underlying messaging as com.google.firebase.messaging.WebpushNotification?  The [Google documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/messaging/WebpushNotification) states that WebpushNotification conforms to the mozilla web notification specification, but doesn't say anything about the underlying message generated by the Notification class.

Comment: The WebpushNotification class is specific to browsers, while the Notification class is specific to mobile devices.  Notification can take an android or ios config.  The problem that I had is that I wanted to send silent notifications through the Java Firebase Admin API, and Notification does not have a silent option (but WebpushNotification does!?!?).

Comment: I think you can find your answer here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/messaging/Message